# mysql strange behavior using subqueries and table alias

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using mysql Server version: 5.5.40-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log (Ubuntu)

This query without table alias : ( performed with phpmyadmin )

```
select id from tableA where id IN
(
  SELECT tableA.id FROM 
         tableA,link_table_A_and_B, tableB WHERE
         tableA.deleted=0 AND 
         tableA.id = link_table_A_and_B.id_to_A AND  
         tableB.id = link_table_A_and_B.id_to_B AND tableB.name LIKE '%xxx%')
```

results in **102 rows** and in this query with table alias:

```
select id from tableA where id IN
(
  SELECT cand.id FROM 
         tableA cand,link_table_A_and_B link, tableB exp WHERE
         cand.deleted=0 AND 
         cand.id = link.id_to_A AND  
         exp.id = link.id_to_B AND exp.name LIKE '%xxx%')
```

results in **192 rows**

How is it possible? ( in my legacy database the involved tables has long name, as well as long FKs names.)
Regards

Comment: If you have the same table in both main/head query and in sub-query, I'd recommend table alises in both places - just to make sure everybody understand whats going on. (Scope rules aren't always fololowed by everybody...)

Comment: Don't use implicit (comma-) join syntax.

Comment: Either the tables' contents changed or this is bug. I suggest you provide the actual queries. My bet would be that by simplifying the queries to post here, you removed what caused this.

Comment: You are probably missing a comma in the from clause in your first query.  A simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.  Also use explicit join syntax.

Comment: Ok, reboot server's machine has solved this problem. But I haven't been able to track what was going on, and probably was my fault. Thank you!